# Error while testing Django with Memcached

Tags: python, django, memcached

I have memcached as my caching back-end on django project. While running `python manage.py test`, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'FakeModel' has no attribute '_deferred'
```

The detailed log is given below:

```
 File "/home/my_project/virtualenv_my_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/cache/backends/memcached.py", line 82, in set
    self._cache.set(key, value, self._get_memcache_timeout(timeout))
  File "/home/my_project/virtualenv_my_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/memcache.py", line 584, in set
    return self._set("set", key, val, time, min_compress_len)
  File "/home/my_project/virtualenv_my_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/memcache.py", line 835, in _set
    return _unsafe_set()
  File "/home/my_project/virtualenv_my_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/memcache.py", line 812, in _unsafe_set
    store_info = self._val_to_store_info(val, min_compress_len)
  File "/home/my_project/virtualenv_my_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/memcache.py", line 782, in _val_to_store_info
    pickler.dump(val)
  File "/home/my_project/virtualenv_my_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 186, in __reduce__
    if self.model._deferred:
AttributeError: type object 'FakeModel' has no attribute '_deferred'
```

The error occurs whenever the cache times out and it needs to store something in cache. If I run my development server and run test again, now error is shown.

**Update:**

Memcached settings:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND':'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION':'127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}
```

One thing I have used for caching is the output returned by the queryset:

```
top_students = Student.objects.filter(.....).filter(
            ..........
        ).annotate(
            .........
        ).all().order_by(........)[:3]
```

The student model goes like this:

```
class Student(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, null=True,
                             blank=True, related_name="student")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    rollno = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    phoneno = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
    enrollYear = models.ForeignKey(EnrollYear, null=True)
    college = models.ForeignKey(College, null=True, blank=True)
    faculty = models.ForeignKey(Faculty, null=True, blank=True)
    verification = models.ManyToManyField(VerifyStudent)
```

Comment: What version of django?

Comment: Its django 1.6 with python2.7

Comment: Please show your models and relevant to the memcached project settings. Thanks.

Comment: Where does `FakeModel` come from?

Comment: Please show running test

Comment: Do you have different settings for your tests? or is the one you're showing shared for dev and test?